# Ifresco API integrates in PHP

Tags: php, drupal, alfresco

We have integrated Alfresco and Drupal(PHP) using Ifresco API.
When we create a content in Drupal, that should be create in Alfresco.

But we are getting error in below line.

```
$nodes = $session->query($spacesStore, "PATH:\"app:company_home/st:sites/cm:test\"");
```

We are getting below error.

```
SoapFault: WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized in SoapClient->__soapCall() (line 68 of E:\xampp\htdocs\indiatv\drupal\sites\all\modules\cmis_api\ifresco\Alfresco\Service\WebService\AlfrescoWebService.php).
```

Please help us in resolving this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the ancient WebServices stuff? Why not use the modern and supported RESTful CMIS interface?